# Collections comparator with null at the end

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I have some `User` objects that can have `name` and `email`, I want them sorted by name , then by email, but firstly show users that have not null names. I was trying like so:

```
 Collections.sort(usersList, new Comparator<User>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(User obj1, User obj2) {
                int res = 0;

               //to make sure null names at the end

                if (obj1.getFullName() == null && obj2.getFullName()  == null)
                    res = 0;

                if (obj1.getFullName()  == null)
                    res = 1;

                if (obj2.getFullName() == null)
                    res = -1;

                //logic for name sorting then email sorting

                if (obj1.getFullName() != null  && obj2.getFullName() != null)
                    res = obj1.getFullName().compareTo(obj2.getFullName());

                if (res == 0)
                    res = obj1.getEmail().compareTo(obj2.getEmail());

                return res;
            }
        });
```

As result  I get names first but sorted by email not by name.

Comment: you probably want "else if" rather than lots of "ifs".  otherwise the "ifs" at the bottom of your method are "winning" - you are going into those ifs even if you've been into the ones above.  did you mean to?

Comment: Get out of the habit of leaving out `{}` for one-line blocks. You'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with Java-8's [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) utilities:

```
List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User("pete", "pete@email"), new User(null, null), new User("alex", null), new User(null, "email"));

Collections.sort(users, Comparator.comparing(User::getName, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                       .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(User::getEmail, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));

System.out.println(users);
```

Output:

```
[
    User{name='alex', email='null'}, 
    User{name='pete', email='pete@email'}, 
    User{name='null', email='email'}, 
    User{name='null', email='null'}
]
```